# How to configure ESLint / Prettier formatting rules on "codesandbox.io"

Tags: javascript, formatting, eslint, prettier, codesandbox

On [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/), how can I configure Prettier so that it doesn't change the line breaks?

Also, how can I deactivate specific ESLint rules. For example, I would like to turn off the `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` rule.
A newly created `eslintrc` file seems to be ignored in my ES201x project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily configure the formatting behaviour of your Sandbox by adding the `prettier` config file in the following way:

1. Create the file `.prettierrc` in the root folder of the Sandbox.
2. Using the JSON syntax add the [formatting rules](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) you want to the file.

For example to change the the line wrapping which I guess annoys most of the people, set the [`printWidth`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) value:

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 25
}
```

3. Save the file and **reload the Sandobox page**.
4. **Next time you save** any of the files the **code will be formatted** following the rules you had set in the `.prettierrc`.

**Other:**

- It seems to be necessary to reload the Sandbox page for the settings to take place. After re-opening it, the file `.prettierrc` will be shown as the UI and not file.
- To add new formatting rules, open the file `.prettierrc` showing as the UI and click on **`Open file in editor`** and add the rules you need.
- Here is [the list of Prettier config options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) you can set in `.prettierrc`.
- **To enable/disable Prettier formatting** do following:
  `Cmd + Shift + P` --> Select `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)` --> Search for `Editor: Format on Save` --> Disable/Enable the option .

**Enjoy!**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. For whatever reason, my custom `"printWidth": 300` was always ignored. In the end, I disabled the prettier formatter completely; just got in the way.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to prevent prettier from removing line-breaks so I just turned off the on-save setting. It doesn't come up too often for me, so it's easy enough to pretty up code in an editor.

I'm hunting for a way to override the eslint rules too

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know there was an option to disable prettier on save. This solution showed me that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this option no longer exists.

Comment: @Sawataytoes you can find/disable by doing the follwoing: `Cmd + Shift + P`  -->    Select `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)`  -->    Search for `Editor: Format on Save`     -->    Disable/Enable the option